# Use Variable outside Firebase Block

Tags: ios, firebase, block, nsuinteger

Hello everyone I'm using Firebase for my ios project ...
I have a lot of trouble using the values of my variables outside of the Firebase blocks when I query the database.

For example in this case I'm trying to get a number value from this query ...

```
 FIRDatabaseReference *userDbRef = FIRDatabase.database.reference;
 [[[userDbRef child:RTDUSER] child:userID] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

     NSUInteger totalCFU = [snapshot.value[RTDUSER_TOTALCFU] unsignedIntegerValue];

} withCancelBlock:nil];
```

I need this number value also obtained outside the block (in other functions of this class) ...

How can I use the TotalCFU variable outside the firebase block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a method from inside the block to handle the value.

```
FIRDatabaseReference *userDbRef = FIRDatabase.database.reference;
 [[[userDbRef child:RTDUSER] child:userID] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    NSUInteger totalCFU = [snapshot.value[RTDUSER_TOTALCFU] unsignedIntegerValue];

    // Call a function to handle value
    [self doSomethingWithCFU: totalCFU];

} withCancelBlock:nil];
```

Somewhere else in your class:

```
(void)doSomethingWithCFU:(NSUInteger)totalCFU {
    // Do something with the value
}
```

Comment: Hello I tried your suggestion but if I insert a nslog immediately after the block (outside) totalCFU returns me a value of ZERO

Comment: Correct, the value gets set when the block executes. Sounds like you might prefer the alternative approach I mentioned. Create a method to handle the new value.

Comment: Ok so I can not manage the variable out of the block by staying in the same method?

Comment: No. The call happens asynchronously. By the time it completes, you will be out of that method.

Comment: ok so what do you mean "outside the block" when you write this?  // Set value so that it can be accessed outside of block

Answer (score 1):

Use `__block` to use your variable outside.

```
FIRDatabaseReference *userDbRef = FIRDatabase.database.reference;
__block NSUInteger totalCF;
[[[userDbRef child:RTDUSER] child:userID] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

     totalCFU = [snapshot.value[RTDUSER_TOTALCFU] unsignedIntegerValue];

} withCancelBlock:nil];
```